# Delta Live Table ignoring the defined schema

Tags: python, azure, pyspark, azure-databricks, delta-live-tables

Using autoloader, I am reading some continues data from storage to Databricks Delta Live table. The declaration of data pipeline is as follows.

```
import dlt
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import *
    
sch = "StructType([StructField('Date', StringType(), True), StructField('machine', StringType(), True), StructField('temperature', DecimalType(), True), StructField('time', StringType(), True)])" 
    
    @dlt.create_table(
      comment="The raw machine data, ingested from azure storage.",
      table_properties={
        "myCompanyPipeline.quality": "raw",
        "pipelines.autoOptimize.managed": "true"
      }
    )
    
    def test_raw():
      return (spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("schema",sch).option("cloudFiles.schemaLocation", "/FileStore/schema").option("cloudFiles.format", "json").load("..../"))
```

And dataset I am reading from storage as below.

```
{"Date":"2023-10-16","time":"12:00:00","machine":"Machine1","temperature":"23.50"}
{"Date":"2023-10-16","time":"12:00:01","machine":"Machine2","temperature":"...corrupt temp..."}
{"Date":"2023-10-16","time":"12:00:02","machine":"Machine3","temperature":"27.50"}
```

But unfortunately, the pipeline is not failing for wrong **"temperature"** data (Non Decimal) and pipeline is processing all records successfully.
Ideally this should get failed because temperature column is defined as Decimal data type.

Can someone please help, why this schema enforcement not working.

Comment: Is `sch` created as a `StructType` object, not as a string? Shouldn't you use `from_json` function to apply the schema, instead of using the `option("schema", sch)` in the `readStream` method?

Comment: I have used StructType not String. You can see the reason of failure in answer part. And the reason I haven't use from_json function is that it would lead to a runtime exception in case of schema and type mismatches what I don't want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved after applying

```
spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").schema(sch)
```

in place of

```
spark.readStream.format("cloudFiles").option("schema",sch)
```

Answer (score 0):

> But unfortunately, the pipeline is not failing for wrong **"temperature"** data (Non Decimal) and pipeline is processing all records successfully. Ideally this should get failed because temperature column is defined as Decimal data type.

You won't get error whenever there is mismatch between schema and data type, it simply makes it has `null` when there is type mismatch.

**Note**: It makes `null` only when you are running pipeline first time. If you already having table with column of different type and provided schema is of different type then you will get error as below.

[image]

For `json` file type it takes everything as string if you don't provide the schema properly.

That is you provided schema in `option("schema",sch)` instead of `schema(sch)`

[image]

So, you won't get any error and it takes everything as string.

Comment: Yes, I have already added the same answer of the problem and it's closed now.  When I posted the question, I was not getting null even there was a schema mismatches. I didn't expect any run time exception but null in data.

Comment: Yes. you will not get null, as i mentioned in your initial code all columns are read as string. You give different table name and schema location with your new spark code
`schema(sch)` then you will get null.